# CSS not loading for Magento 2

Tags: magento2, error, static-content, static-content-deploy

After updating Magento 2 from version 2.1.7 to 2.1.8 there is no css loading for the backend (front end works fine). **How can I get the css to load for the admin?**

**After deploying static content I got this error:**

[image]

Comment: Delete var/view_proprocessed `rm -rf var/view_preprocessed` from root, run `bin/magento setup:di:compile` command and try to deploy static again.

Comment: delete view_preprocessed before generating static files

Comment: @BareFeet setup:static-content:deploy ;-) not di compile

Comment: @PhilippSander Yes, you are right! I do apologise, also make sure you define the language too. I use `en_GB` on my site and have to define it every time. E.g. `setup:static-content:deploy en_GB`. By default it deploys `en_US`.

Comment: @PhilippSander I deleted view-processed and then ran setup:static-content:deploy en_GB en_US nl_NL but I still have the same error.

Comment: well is that viriable defined anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this problem by disabling all my extensions and then enabling then one at a time until I found that there was one which was causing the problem.